# Get User's (Active Directory) Department based on TFS TeamFoundationIdentity

Tags: tfs, active-directory, identity

I have a .Net application that post-processes (manual) tests performed in TFS2010 via the Microsoft Test Manager and the individual [ITestCaseResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.client.itestcaseresult%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instances do have a [TeamFoundationIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.client.teamfoundationidentity%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on their [.RunBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.client.itestcaseresult.runby%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property assigned and I was wondering how / if I could retrieve the users' departments based on this identity.

The Tfs Users are (active directory) domain-wide users but the TeamFoundationIdentity does not *seem* to allow direct access to the underlying windows / ad one so I was wondering if there's a common denominator between the Tfs and the Windows identity that I could use to retrieve the department(s)?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things on a TeamFoundationIdentity that can get you back to the AD account.  First, the domain name and account name should be the same.  With those values you should be able to retrieve the domain identity with the form "domain\accountName".  Also, the TeamFoundationId is a GUID that is *usually* copied directly from AD.  I am not too up-to-date with AD APIs but that should get you close.